# How to obtain an isotropic functional of a symmetric tensor which satisfies a given first derivative?

Tags: linear-algebra

I do have a problem in continuum mechanics for which I kindly ask for your help. How can I obtain the isotropic scalar-valued functional $\psi(\boldsymbol{U})$ that satisfies the derivative

$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \boldsymbol{U}}=\ln (\det(\boldsymbol{U})) ~\boldsymbol{1}$$

in which $\boldsymbol{1}$ represents the unit tensor. I already tried to solve the question in a systematic way: Construct the functional $\psi(I_1,I_2,I_3)$ with the invariants $I_1= \boldsymbol{U}:\boldsymbol{1}$, $I_2= \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{U}:\boldsymbol{U}$ and $I_3=\det(\boldsymbol{U})$ and calculate the derivative

$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \boldsymbol{U}}=\psi_1~\boldsymbol{1}+\psi_2~\boldsymbol{U}+\psi_3~I_3~\boldsymbol{U}^{-1}$$

with $\psi_j=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial I_j}$.

My "best" solution was to set $\psi=\ln(I_3)I_1$ but this results in an additional (unwanted) term:

$\psi_1=\ln(I_3)$ and $\psi_3=I_1 I_3^{-1}$ and finally

$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \boldsymbol{U}}=\ln(I_3)~\boldsymbol{1}+I_1~\boldsymbol{U}^{-1}$$.

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @adtzir, and welcome to the MathOverflow: the topic in your question remembers me very much of the researches of Ronald Rivlin and hi school: perhaps having a look at his  "Collected papers" you'll find something useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Daniele Tampieri! Well, the question seems fairly simple and common for someone who is familiar with isotropic hyperelasticity. However, the product of a logarithm of the determinant in combination with the unit tensor is the thing that makes this question tricky. I still have some ideas in mind. I'm mostly interested in good structured methods to find an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, we can try the case where $U$ is a two by two
matrix $$U = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
and we want a function $\psi(U)$  that satisfies
$$ \psi_a = \ln(ad-bc), \qquad \psi_b = 0, \qquad \psi_c = 0, \qquad \psi_d = \ln(ad-bc).$$ There does not seem to be any solution unless you restrict $U$ to multiples of the identity matrix:

Suppose you have a solution. Equality of mixed partials gives $\psi_{ab} = 0 = \frac{c}{ad-bc}$ so that $c = 0$. Similarly $b = 0$ and
we still need $$\psi_a = \psi_d = \ln(ad).$$ Now equality of mixed partials gives
$$ \psi_{ad} = \frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{d}$$. Therefore $a = d$.

Comment: Thank you very much @bob-terell! This helped me a lot. Just one little follow-up question to complete the proposed method. Let's assume I do have a matrix-valued (or tensor-rank2-valued) function $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial U} = \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{U})$ for which the mixed partials do not restrict $\boldsymbol{U}$ to be of any special case (like multiples of the identity matrix in the above example). How can I obtain $\psi$? Is it just component-wise integrating the first partial derivatives?

Comment: I tried another example: $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \boldsymbol{U}} = tr(\boldsymbol{U}) \boldsymbol{1} - \boldsymbol{U}$. In this case I know the solution of $\psi$. $\psi_a=a+d-a$, $\psi_b=a+d-d$ and $\psi_b=-b$ and $\psi_c=-c$. Integration of $\psi_a$ gives $ad$ and integration of $\psi_b$ gives $-\frac{b^2}{2}$ (the same for $c$). The "intelligent" combination of the component-wise integrations yields $\psi=ad-\frac{b^2}{2}-\frac{c^2}{2}$ which is correct. So for the off-diagonal terms the sum is ok but for the diagonal terms I had to divide the sum by the dimension of the matrix (2).

Comment: I think your suggestion of component-wise integrating is the best way. But you should compare what is recommended in most calculus books (for the case of just 3 variables), to check that a vector valued function f is a gradient, see whether the curl of f is zero. That is, see whether the crossed derivatives agree, $f_{i,j} = f_{j,i}$. But if they do you still have to integrate, so I agree with you. Start by integrating the components of f  and see whether it works or not.